# Gnu Bison shift / reduce conflicts in indentation-based grammar describing hierarchical expressions

Tags: parsing, gnu, bison, flex-lexer

I've been not using Bison for a long time, so there is a chance I'm missing something simple here, however, I cannot figure out why the following grammar produces shift / reduce conflicts. I think the following grammar is not ambiguous. It's purpose is to parse expressions like:

```
a b
  c d
    e f
  g h
```

as (in pseudo-AST):

```
App 
    (App a b) 
    (Seq 
        [ App 
              (App c d) 
              (Seq [App e f])
        , (App g h)
        ]
    )
```

The grammar:

```
%token <Token> VAR
%token <Token> EOL

%token <Token> INDENT_INC
%token <Token> INDENT_DEC

%token <AST> CONS
%token <AST> WILDCARD
%type  <AST> expr
%type  <AST> subExpr
%type  <AST> block
%type  <AST> tok

%start program

%%
program:
  expr { result = $1; }

expr:
  subExpr  {$$=$1;}
| subExpr EOL INDENT_INC block { $$ = AST.app($1,$3); } 

subExpr:
  tok          {$$=$1;}
| subExpr tok  {$$ = AST.app($1,$2); } 

block:
  expr  {$$=$1;}
| block EOL expr {$$=AST.seq($1,$3);} // causes error

tok:
  VAR { $$ = AST.fromToken($1); }
%%
```

The error is just `2 shift/reduce conflicts`. When debugging the parser, we can observe:

```
Grammar

    0 $accept: program $end
    1 program: expr
    2 expr: subExpr
    3     | subExpr EOL INDENT_INC block
    4 subExpr: tok
    5        | subExpr tok
    6 block: expr
    7      | block EOL expr
    8 tok: VAR

[...]

State 4

    2 expr: subExpr .
    3     | subExpr . EOL INDENT_INC block
    5 subExpr: subExpr . tok

    VAR  shift, and go to state 1
    EOL  shift, and go to state 7

    EOL       [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    $default  reduce using rule 2 (expr)

    tok  go to state 8

[...]

State 11

    3 expr: subExpr EOL INDENT_INC block .
    7 block: block . EOL expr

    EOL  shift, and go to state 12

    EOL       [reduce using rule 3 (expr)]
    $default  reduce using rule 3 (expr)
```

And to be honest, I'm not convinced where the ambiguity comes from. I'd be thankful for any help on how to remove the conflicts in such a grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grammar does not use `INDENT_DEC`; without that, you cannot know where an indented `block` ends.

In effect, that's what those shift/reduce conflicts are telling you. Since the grammar doesn't see `INDENT_DEC`, it cannot distinguish between the `EOL` which separates two `expr`s in the same block and the `EOL` which terminates a `block`. Thus, an `EOL` is ambiguous (provided at least one `INDENT_INC` has been seen).

Here's a simple demonstration of ambiguity. The expression to parse is:

```
a EOL INDENT_INC b EOL INDENT_INC c EOL d
```

Here are two leftmost derivations, which differ in where `d` is nested (I condensed the `subexpr ⇒ var ⇒ TOK` path for simplicity):

```
# Here, d belongs to the outer subexpr (effectively, a single indent)
expr ⇒ subexpr EOL INDENT_INC block
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC block
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC block                          EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC expr                           EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC subexpr EOL INDENT_INC block   EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC subexpr EOL INDENT_INC expr    EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC subexpr EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (c) EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (c) EOL subexpr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (c) EOL TOK (d)

# Here, d belongs to the inner subexpr (effectively two indents)
expr ⇒ subexpr EOL INDENT_INC block
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC block
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC subexpr EOL INDENT_INC block
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC block
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC block   EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC expr    EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC subexpr EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (c) EOL expr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (c) EOL subexpr
     ⇒ TOK (a) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (b) EOL INDENT_INC TOK (c) EOL TOK (d)
```

So the grammar really is ambiguous. But the shift/reduce conflicts don't directly point at the ambiguity. They point at the problem of deciding whether or not to reduce the construct before the `EOL` without seeing the symbol following the `EOL`. This is the essence of the LR(1) restriction: Every reduction must be made before shifting the next symbol, so even if a grammar would be unambiguous if you could see far enough into the future it will still have shift/reduce conflicts if the reduction decision could go either way.

Comment: Thank you, I was suspecting something along these lines (that’s why I mentioned INDENT_DEC in the code), but now I don’t really understand how it relates to the Bison algorithm. I understand that we are limited to a single lookahead token, but still I feel we should not need the INDENT_DEC to disambiguate the grammar. When we get EOL we shift it. Then we can inspect the next token. If on the lookahead position there is INDENT_INC, the only possible reduction is “expr”. Otherwise, the only possible reduction is “block”. So why Bison cannot decide it?

Comment: @WojciechDanilo: I edited the answer to illustrate the ambiguity and to offer an explanation of why you can't just shift `EOL` (because you might need to reduce the phrase before the `EOL` before you see the token following it).

Comment: thank you so much for your time and such a detailed explanation. It makes now perfect sense and also it's very clear to me why it's ambiguous. I don't know why I did not realize it earlier – after your explanation, it's "obvious"! Rici, thank you a thousand times!